# How to automatically detect an HTML tag if it contains a certain attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js, wow.js

How to automatically detect an HTML tag if it contains a certain attribute like `data-wow-delay`? This is from wow.js.

What I want to do is that if an HTML tag contains the said attribute, it will automatically add the classes `wow bounce` in the tag.

##### Example

###### HTML

```html
<h1 data-wow-delay="0.2s">
    sample
</h1>
```

###### JS (this is where I am at lost, not sure how to start it)

###### Outcome should be something like this when inspected

```html
<h1
    class="wow bounce"
    data-wow-delay="0.2s"
>
    sample
</h1>
```

***Note:*** there are a lot of different HTML tags that use this attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Element.hasAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/hasAttribute) to check whether the element contains the specified attribute:

```js
const elem = document.querySelector('h1');

if(elem.hasAttribute('data-wow-delay')){
  elem.classList.add('wow', 'bounce')
}
```

```css
.wow.bounce{
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-wow-delay="0.2s">
  sample
</h1>
```

Alternatively, you can use `querySelectorAll` and the [CSS attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) to select all elements with the attribute:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('[data-wow-delay]').forEach(e => e.classList.add('wow','bounce'))
```

```css
.wow.bounce{
  background-color:grey;
}
```

```html
<h1 data-wow-delay="0.2s">
  sample
</h1>

<p data-wow-delay="0.1s">sample</p>
```